# Confused about using logical operators

Tags: java

I have an assignment/project to write a program that displays the integers between 1 and 100 that are divisible by 6 or 7, but not both. It does not work the way I've written it below. Is my boolean value correct for what the question is asking?

```
import acm program.*;

public class SixAndSeven extends ConsoleProgram {
    public void run() {
        for (int n = 1; n < 100; n++) {
            boolean year = (n % 6 ==0) ||
                (n % 7 ==0) &&
                !(n % 6 == 0) &&
                ( n % 7 ==0);

             if (year) {
                 println(year);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, then no, it's not correct ;)

Comment: To be more helpful, you should edit your program to display the value of each of your boolean terms for the values that don't give the correct answer.

Comment: I think you'll want to print n instead of the boolean year. Also you probably want to change the second half to !((n % 6 == 0) && (n % 7 == 0))

Comment: @user1333371 yes thanks that was a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do the below

```
boolean year = ((n % 6 ==0) || (n % 7 ==0)) && !((n % 6 == 0) && ( n % 7 ==0));
```

Basically group the 2 sets of conditions within a `()` before negating, so that the conditions apply correctly to both.

To make it more readable, you could do this.. (though perhaps overkill..)

```
boolean divisbleby6 = n%6 == 0;
boolean divisbleby7 = n%7 == 0;
boolean divisibleby6and7 = divisbleby6 && divisbleby7 ;

boolean year = (divisbleby6 || divisbleby7) && !divisibleby6and7 ;
```

or the clever method suggested by Mel (possibly harder to understand at a glance), which returns `true` only if one but not both conditions are true.

```
boolean year = divisbleby6 != divisbleby7;
```

P.S. Additionally, as  user1333371  suggests, you probably want to do `println(n);`

Comment: I did not notice that thanks.

Comment: +1. Consider using `boolean mod6 = (n%6==0); mod7 = (mod7%==0);` so you don't need to redo work.  It also allow you to `return mod6 != mod7` which is cute.

Comment: I really would not recommend using `boolean x = divisbleby6 != divisbleby7;` It took me a long time to figure out what that was doing. That's very clever code, and I don't mean that as a compliment.

Comment: @DanielKaplan true, have added the caveat.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply write like below:

```
boolean year = (n % 6 == 0) != (n % 7 == 0)
```

Comment: Or use XOR instead of not-equals. Best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use parenthesis to set the order of operations and make sure the negation applies to the modulo check for both 6 and 7.

```
import acm program.*;

public class SixAndSeven extends ConsoleProgram {
public void run(){

for (int n = 1; n < 100; n++) {

boolean year = ((n % 6 == 0) || (n % 7 == 0))
                    && !((n % 6 == 0) && (n % 7 == 0));

            if (year) {
                System.out.println(n);
            }

}
```